# does a simple-recovery database records transaction logs when selected from a full-recovery database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, transactions

does a simple-recovery database records transaction logs when selected from a full-recovery database? I mean, we have a full-recovery database, and it records too much transaction logs, causing its size to grow.

my question is, does the simple recovery still has does its minimal logging even if the data are selected from a full-recovery model database? thank you!

Comment: Usually, the `SELECT` is the least of your problems when looking at transaction log usage.....

Comment: `select`ing values from a table does not fill the transaction log.  The `into` is in the other database, so the transaction log of the first database won't be affected.

Comment: Sounds like your time will be better spent devising a transaction log backup schedule and file sizing arrangements that allow the DB to operate in fully recovery at a stable size.

Comment: Why do you think that copying data (so that you now have two copies) reduces log generation? This is a rather strange concept.

Answer (score 1):

One thing has nothing to do with the other. Where the data comes from does not affect logging of changes to the tables in the db it's going to.

However as Martin Smith pointed out this is solving a symptom, there's naff all point in having full recovery mode on if you (they??) aren't backing up the transaction logs frequently enough to make the overhead useful. Whole point of them, aside from restoring up to particular  transaction in the event of some catastrophy in your applications is speed and granularity.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the MSDN page for recovery models.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx

Here is a quick summary from MSDN.

```
1 - Simple model - Automatically reclaims log space to keep space requirements small,
essentially eliminating the need to manage the transaction log space

2 - Bulk Copy model - 

An adjunct of the full recovery model that permits high-performance 
bulk copy operations.

**The first two do not support point in time recovery!**

3 - Full model - Can recover to an arbitrary point in time 
(for example, prior to application or user error). 
If no tail log backup possible, recover to last log backup.
```

So your problem is with either **log usage or log backups.**

A - Are you deleting from temporary tables instead of truncating?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx  The delete operating will log each row in the transaction log.

B - Are you inserting large amounts of data via a ETL job?  Each insert will get logged in the T-Log.

If you use bulk copy and ETL that support (fast data loads), it will be minimally logged.
However, page density and fill factor come into play when determining the size of the T-LOG.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2011/01/07/using-bulk-logged-recovery-model-for-bulk-operations-will-reduce-the-size-of-transaction-log-backups-myths-and-truths.aspx

C - How often are you taking transaction log backups?  After each backup, the T-LOG space can be reused.  Resulting in overall smaller size.

D - How fragmented is the T-LOG?  I suggest reducing and re-growing the log during a maintenance period.  A 20% log to data ratio with hourly backups worked fine at my old company.  It all depends on how many changes you are making. http://craftydba.com/?p=3374

In summary, these are the places you should be looking at.  Not the old data in the system since it is probably not being modified.

Moving the old data to a read only reporting database so that ADHOC queries from novice T-SQL users **might not be a bad idea**.  But that solves other problems, possible BLOCKING and DEADLOCKS in your OLTP database.

Comment: The other way you get high transaction counts is a lot of throughput on the same keys, high speed/ high volume data collection is a classic. Mind you full recovery option is usually a waste of effort in that scenario.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I totally agree.  But if your volume is that high and constant changes to the data, why not use a in memory table - Hakaton.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2014/01/15/sql-server-2014-inside-hekaton-natively-compiled-stored-procedures.aspx

Comment: In the case in question because I didn't know enough at the time, saying that I'm still not sure I could have afforded that option. Certainly should have been a consideration though. I used to be its data, reach for the SQL Hammer guy back then. :(